# 'ontouchstart' on document.documentElement is true in Chrome 58

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

hi，there is my conputer with chrome that shows *'ontouchstart' on document.documentElement* is *true*, while it's thinkpad t440p, not a mobile device, reflects bootstrap dropdown insert a div with class dropdown-backdrop

Answer (score 0):

If you use `'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement` it should work in Chrome just fine. (I just used it yesterday, and it correctly returned false for Chrome .)

Please note that `in` is a JavaScript operator, but "on" most certainly is not! I'm pretty sure that is the problem.